# why does Allah Hate me?

Tags: women, punishment

Salam,
Why does Allah Hate me? Whether I be good or evil, after some time I feel that Allah Hates me. He put me into a horrible life and I have been trying to get out since I was a child, crying my eyes out to Him every day, working so hard. But He doesn't get me out. He Sees me suffer every day and I keep feeling He Hates me. I used to follow Islam to the letter before despite all my suffering. And I used to think the whole thing's a test and it'll be over one day inshAllah. My pain took me close to Allah. But now it's taking me away from Him. That's what Ali Rz said about the difference between a trial that's a punishment and one that's a test. The former takes you away from Allah. I sin a lot now. But I used to feel Allah Hated me back then and He Hates me now. There isnt a single day that I have been happy or a single day that i knew I'll one day be outta my prison, as a house mostly is for a girl in this filthy country. I pray to Allah to give me death with His Mercy if that's the only way I can be free because suicide is haram. Once in my childhood I prayed for trial and afflictions and He granted my prayers though I was only a silly child. But all the good things that I asked for at the time.. I don't know... Allah Hates me. He has given me pain since the day I was born and He punishes me for my sins but He doesn't comfort me in my pain. In the least bit, I need Him to tell me that He loves me and I'll be happy in my suffering. But He doesn't. Even though i feel He Hates me all the time. He Has always Hated me.

Comment: This looks like an issue of discussion rather than a practical and answerable question about the topic of Islam. As-written, it is a poor fit for this site.

Answer (score 3):

### Hard life is not a sign for hate

You say:

> He put me into a horrible life

This is never a sign of hating you, it could be he is preparing the best life for you:

- Prophet Mohammad did not see his Father, did not enjoy his mother long, he had to work as shepherd for very low return, he was called a liar, magician and crazy, he was hurt physically and morally by his own people, and much more, he was even poisoned, do you think Allah hated his prophet? No. He is the best man lived on earth.
- Jacob and Youssuf, the father and son are bot
  h prophets, the Father lost his son for 40 years, and lost his sight, Youssuf was sold as a slave, jailed, for years, do you think Allah hated him? No but he made him in charge for that land.

You say

> And I used to think the whole thing's a test

You were right, the whole life is a test, the hard times and the good times, the more you grow , and the more experience in life you gain, you learn to find the wisdom behind things, learn from the story of Moussa (PBUH) with Al-Khader, things may look bad but they are not.

### Like and Hate

Allah will like you as long as you keep faith and do not become disbeliever.
Allah will not like you insist to pass the limits and end while doing that.
The man ho killed 100 person, Allah ordered the land to get closer to the good people so he entered Jannah because he only decided to repent.

### You decide whether he likes or hates you

Your actions will decide if Allah likes or hate you, there is no way that you submit to him as he ordered and he will hate you.

### one of many things makes Allah likes you

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>   Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "Allah the Exalted has said: 'I will declare war against him who shows hostility to a pious worshipper of Mine. And the most beloved thing with which My slave comes nearer to Me is what I have enjoined upon him; and My slave keeps on coming closer to Me through performing Nawafil (prayer or doing extra deeds besides what is obligatory) till I love him. When I love him I become his hearing with which he hears, his seeing with which he sees, his hand with which he strikes, and his leg with which he walks; and if he asks (something) from Me, I give him, and if he asks My Protection (refuge), I protect him".

[Al- Bukhari].

### One of many signs will help you know when he likes you

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>   Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "If Allah loves a person, He calls Gabriel, saying, 'Allah loves so and so, O Gabriel love him' So Gabriel would love him and then would make an announcement in the Heavens: 'Allah has loved so and-so therefore you should love him also.' So all the dwellers of the Heavens would love him, and then he is granted the pleasure of the people on the earth." (See Hadith No. 66, Vol. 8)

Do not give up, Jannah is not a cheap thing you may gain while sitting lazy...
May Allah Guide you to the right path.

Answer (score -1):

Allah forgave all sings and never give up the hope.allah created you because allah loves you.people are good and bad stay away those who you think harming you.I wish you allah remove all your stress